# I am facing the error in pandas_DataReader and yfinance

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

These are the libraries I import

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime as dt
import yfinance as yf
```

These are the lines in which the errors occur

```
 # load Data
    company = 'fb'
    start = dt.datetime(2012, 1, 1)
    end = dt.datetime(2020, 1, 1)

    df = yf.download(tickers=['^GSPC'], start=start, end=end)
    data = web.DataReader(company, 'yahoo', start, end)
```

These are the list of error I get:

```
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\python.exe F:\pythonProject\main.py 
    [*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "F:\pythonProject\main.py", line 19, in <module>
        data = web.DataReader(company, 'yahoo', start, end)
      File "C:\Users\Deepanshu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py",      line 211, in wrapper
        return func(*args, **kwargs)`your text`
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 379, in DataReader
    ).read()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 253, in read
        df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py", line 153, in _read_one_data
        data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

this is the program i write to predict stock price. I am writing this program in  pycharm IDE. I added the yfinance library but i get the same error every time I run.

Comment: The symbol of fb is META on yahoo finance. It will not find fb. Look at code I provide below

Answer (score 0):

Add `yf.pdr_override()` to resolve issues and fb is meta

```
yf.pdr_override() # add this 

df = yf.download(tickers=['^GSPC'], start="2017-01-01", end="2017-04-30")

# fb is meta 
data = web.DataReader('META', start = dt.datetime(2012, 1, 1), end = dt.datetime(2020, 1, 1))
print(df.head(5))
print("=================================")
print(data.head(5))
print()
```